# validating form via jquery ajax doens't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I've written a function which should actually validate the form data. It checks if each input has a value and whether the email format is right. when everything is fine, it should submit that form and send it via php. This is done in Ajax, as I don't want a page refresh. Also, the submit-button should change its value  when the form is sending.

here is my jsfiddle, as it is a lot of code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qY6uu/

```
    <form  id="form" method="POST">
        <input type="text" class="" name="name" placeholder="Bitte verrate uns Deinen Namen."  id="anfrage-name"/>  
        <input type="email" class="" name="email" placeholder="Und nun Deine E-Mail-Adresse..." id="anfrage-email"/>
        <textarea name="message" class="" placeholder="...gefolgt von Deiner Nachricht an uns." rows="6" id="anfrage-kaufen"></textarea>
        <span id="error-message"></span>
       <input type="submit" class="send-button" value="Anfragen" id="anfrage-abschicken"/>
   </form>
```

and here my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('#form'); // contact form
  var submit_button = $('#anfrage-abschicken');  // submit button
  var error = $('#error-message'); // alert div for show alert message

  // form submit event
  $('#anfrage-abschicken').click(function() {
       var sEmail = $('#anfrage-email').val();
        var sName = $('#anfrage-name').val();
        var sMessage = $('#anfrage-kaufen').val();

        //if nothing is in
        if ($.trim(sMessage).length == 0 && $.trim(sName).length == 0 && $.trim(sEmail).length == 0){
            $('#error-message').text('Alle Felder müssen ausgefüllt werden.');
            return false;
        }

        //no name
        else if ($.trim(sName).length == 0 ) {
            $('#error-message').text('Bitte verrate uns Deinen Namen.');
            $('#anfrage-name').focus();
            return false;
        }

        //no email
        else if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0 ) { 
            $('#error-message').text('Deine E-Mail-Adresse musst Du angeben, damit wir Dir anworten können.');
            $('#anfrage-email').focus();
            return false;
        }

        //No message
        else if ($.trim(sMessage).length == 0 ) { 
            $('#error-message').text('Eine Nachricht musst Du uns schon hinterlassen.');
            $('#anfrage-kaufen').focus();
            return false;
        }

        //if everything is right (name, message, email, email format)
        else if (validateEmail(sEmail) && $.trim(sMessage).length > 0 && $.trim(sName).length > 0 && $.trim(sEmail).length > 0) {
           $.ajax({
                url: '', // form action url
                type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
                dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
                data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
                beforeSend: function() {
                    error.fadeOut();
                    submit_button.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    error.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
                    form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                    submit_button.html('Send Email'); // reset submit button text
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            });
        }

        //wroong email format 
        else {
            $('#error-message').text('Dein E-Mail-Format stimmt nicht.');
            $('#anfrage-email').focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

//function for validating email format
function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the validateEmail code. Also, there is no need to check `&& $.trim(sMessage).length > 0 && $.trim(sName).length > 0 && $.trim(sEmail).length > 0` just before the ajax request as you have already check so the length is > 0 prior to this if statement.

Comment: yeah i checked it because ut if nothing is in the form, it will show up a message. And I only want to execute the ajax function when each input is right! The validateEmail is below

Comment: Don't use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless your question is about the jQuery Validate plugin.  The tag description is clearly revealed when selecting tags... please slow down, read its description, and don't choose it if it has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Button value need to change not html. you need to change `val()`.

Change your:

```
submit_button.html('Send Email');
```

to:

```
submit_button.val('Send Email');
```

you need prevent default of form submission by `event.preventDefault()`
<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qY6uu/1/)</kbd>

Comment: @fjw : try this and let me know if it is work or not. See my fiddle jquery.

Comment: yeah, in jsfiddle it works, but in dreamweaver and preview in firefox unfortunately not... :D

Comment: then it is not the problem in this part of jquery. It seems that you have more javascript. some where this form is submitted by jquery `form.submit()`

Answer (score 0):

Your button is a submit button so whenever you click on submit button it gets submitted. It won't wait for the javascript code to be executed.

Change your submit button to button type instead of submit type like

```
<input type="button" class="send-button" value="Anfragen" id="anfrage-abschicken"/>
```

Then click on the button will not trigger form submit. Then onclick of the button your javascript code will code will be executed.

Comment: i've changed that, but it still refreshes the page

Comment: Here is updated fiddle page link it works fine with the change of button type http://jsfiddle.net/qY6uu/2/

Comment: May be you should check in some developer tool weather your changes are being reflected or not. without a submit button there is no way form gets submitted and page gets refreshed

Comment: Ok. I know the problem and now it works. BUT... it loads the page into the textarea.. :D wtf?